# What is wrong with my PSQL view table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables player and match:

```
CREATE TABLE player(
id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE match(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
winner serial REFERENCES player(id) NOT NULL,
loser serial REFERENCES player(id) NOT NULL CHECK (loser != winner)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE playerid_sequence
start 1
increment 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE matchid_sequence
start 1
increment 1;
```

I want to create a view table that joins the two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW matchplayers AS
SELECT winner.name, loser.name, m.id 
from player winner, player loser, match m
WHERE m.winner = winner.id AND m.loser = loser.id;
```

But it is returning an error that "name" has been mentioned more than once. Fairly inexperienced to SQL

Comment: You need to add an alias to the `name` columns (the schema doesn't appear in the name Postgres generates for you when you don't provide one). Use `SELECT winner.name AS winner_name, loser.name AS loser_name, ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE VIEW matchplayers AS
SELECT winner.name as winner_name, loser.name as loser_name, m.id 
from player winner, player loser, match m
WHERE m.winner = winner.id AND m.loser = loser.id;
```

to get unambiguous column names of the view.

Comment: you beat my by 0.5 seconds: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/01edf.  good work.

Comment: what does this syntax mean  `from player winner, player loser` ?. I use `from tableA, tableB` usually. thanks

Comment: @AlainIb - `match` is joined twice to `player` to get two different rows (one for a winner and the other for a loser).